# Symfony2 - Atualizar campo de uma entidade ao executar ação em Controller de outra entidade

Tags: mysql, symfony-2, doctrine-2

Preciso atualizar o campo *budget* da minha entidade **Client** ao inserir novo dado na tabela **Budget**. Ambos tem relação *oneToMany* e *manyToOne*, respectivamente. Recebi sugestões para utilizar o conceito de OO para fazer esta operação, então foi sugerido algo mais ou menos desta meneira para mim:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $manager->persist($form->getData());
    $manager->flush();

    $Client = $manager->find('PanelBundle:Client', $form['client_id']->getData()->getId());
    $Client->setBudget($manager->getRepository('PanelBundle:Budget')->getLastId());

    $this->addFlash('success', 'Novo orçamento adicionado');

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('panel_budgets'));
}
```

Ao ver a saída de `$Client`, quando atribuído à variável o método `find`, é exibido o campo *name* do *id* respectivo, que é o *id* do **Client** selecionado por um `select` e passado à variável ao efetuar a submissão do formulário.

Mesmo não ocorrendo nenhum erro, este campo não é atualizado ao efetuar o cadastro. Eu tentei de outra maneira escrevendo uma função específica para atualizar, procurando exemplos, mas obtive erros de semântica inválida.

Como eu poderia atualizar o campo *budget* ao executar o método `addAction` do controller da entidade **Budget**?

Answer (score 1):

Está tudo certo no seu código. Você só esqueceu de persistir o `$Client` e dar o `flush`, da mesma forma que você faz com o budget.

```
$Client->setBudget($manager->getRepository('PanelBundle:Budget')->getLastId());

$manager->persist($Client);
$manager->flush();
```

Comment: Olá! Está dando erro `Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given `. Fiz algumas tentativas de mudança mas sem sucesso. O erro está claro, estou passando uma string ao invés de um objeto. Tentei instanciar o **Client** mas nada mudou. Tens alguma outra sugestão? Obrigado!

Comment: Você precisa passar o objeto budget para o client, não o id do mesmo. Faça assim: `$Client->setBudget($manager->getRepository('PanelBundle:Budget')->getLast())` e crie um método `getLast` no qual você recupera o último budget inserido.

Comment: Se fiz certo, está retornando um erro que diz que o objeto não pode ser convertido para string, então criei um `__toString()` retornando o _address_ da entidade mas mesmo assim nada é modificado em **Client**. Veja só, eu tenho uma outra questão no site global http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441630/trying-to-update-one-table-after-inserting-into-another-one-with-symfony2-and-do que fiz de uma maneira diferente. Será que você poderia fazer a gentileza de olhar e me responder aqui o que você sabe sobre este método? Obrigado, estou ficando levemente desesperado já.

Comment: Esse erro acontece porque você provavelmente está tentando usar o objeto como argumento em um formulário, mas o renderizador de formulários não sabe que atributo usar, e também que o método `__toString()` não está implementado. Você já viu no banco de dados se o objeto foi inserido e o budget para o cliente foi atualizado?

Comment: Usando o objeto como argumento em um formulário? Não se se compreendi. Quanto ao método `__toString()`, com ou sem ele me traz problemas, dependendo da forma que eu deixar o Controller. Ou dá erro dizendo que era esperado um array, mas foi retornado um String, ou que veio um objeto mas era esperado um array. Está uma loucura e eu não sei mais o que fazer. Vou perguntar novamente fornecendo mais informações.